# How to display certain rows from mysql with variable sent via HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get certain data which meets the criteria from the database using AND condition with user searchable HTML form which sends the data to the search.

Code:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

if (isset($_POST['Kohderyhmä']) &&
isset($_POST['Näytön aste']) &&
isset($_POST['Vaikutusten vahvuus']) &&
isset($_POST['Käyttökelpoisuus']) &&
isset($_POST['text']))
{
$Kohderyhmä = get_post($conn, 'Kohderyhmä');
$Näytön_aste = get_post($conn, 'Näytön aste');
$Vaikutusten_vahvuus = get_post($conn, 'Vaikutusten vahvuus');
$Käyttökelpoisuus = get_post($conn, 'Käyttökelpoisuus');
$text = get_post($conn, 'text');


    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta`
        WHERE Kohderyhmä='$Kohderyhmä' AND `Näytön aste`='$Näytön_aste' AND `Vaikutusten vahvuus`='$Vaikutusten_vahvuus' AND `Käyttökelpoisuus: luokka`='$Käyttökelpoisuus'";
         }

  $results = $conn->query($query);
if (!$results) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

$rows = $results->num_rows;
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
$results->data_seek($j);
$row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo '<h3>' . $row['Nimi'] . '</h3><br />';
echo ''  . $row['Kokonaisarvio'] .   '<br />';
echo ''  . $row['Kuvaus'] .  '<br /><br />';

}
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

<b>Kohderyhmä</b><br />
<select name="Kohderyhmä" style="width: 150px;">
<option value="Kaikki">Kaikki</option>
<option value="Pikkulapset">Pikkulapset</option>
<option value="Alle kouluikäiset">Alle kouluikäiset</option>
<option value="Alakouluikäiset">Alakouluikäiset</option>
<option value="Nuoret">Nuoret</option>
<option value="Perheet">Perheet</option>
<option value="Vanhemmat">Vanhemmat</option>
<option value="Työntekijät">Työntekijät</option>
</select>
<br />

<b>Näytön aste</b>
<select name="Näytön aste" style="width: 150px;">
<option value="Kaikki">Kaikki</option>
<option value="Vahva">Vahva</option>
<option value="Kohtalainen">Kohtalainen</option>
<option value="Heikko">Heikko</option>
<option value="Ei riittävää näyttöä">Ei riittävää näyttöä</option>
<option value="Ei arvioitu">Ei arvioitu</option>
</select>
<br />

<b>Vaikutusten vahvuus</b>
<select name="Vaikutusten vahvuus" style="width: 150px;">
  <option value="Kaikki">Kaikki</option>
  <option value="Vahva">Vahva</option>
  <option value="Kohtalainen">Kohtalainen</option>
  <option value="Heikko">Heikko</option>
  <option value="Ei vaikutusta">Ei vaikutusta</option>
  <option value="Ei arvioitu">Ei arvioitu</option>
</select>
<br />

<b>Käyttökelpoisuus</b>
<select name="Käyttökelpoisuus" style="width: 150px;">
  <option value="Kaikki">Kaikki</option>
  <option value="Vahva">Vahva</option>
  <option value="Kohtalainen">Kohtalainen</option>
  <option value="Heikko">Heikko</option>
  <option value="Ei käyttökelpoinen">Ei käyttökelpoinen</option>
  <option value="Ei arvioitu">Ei arvioitu</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
&nbsp;

Haku:        <input type="text" name="text" />
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Hae" />
    </form>
```

I haven't used PHP to contact database before so the PHP code is very messy.
I don't understand any more than the very basics from PHP, I haven't used variables or objects or anything complex before.

HTML form:
variable1
variable2
variable3
variable4
variable5
--->
PHP script:
select * from db
where variable1 and variable2 and variable3 and variable4
--->
display results matching the criteria

Current code causes this error message in error_log:
PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Empty query in /home/user/public_html/folder/script.php on line 23

I have already tried over 15 different variations of variables and sql query in total and nothing has worked..

Comment: Add '`' before and after field name if you wish to use space in field/column  name.

Comment: `<option>` does NOT have name attributes, only `<select>` does.

Comment: What do you mean @Fred -ii-? Do I need to add one or change the code to something else?

Comment: `<option name="Kaikki" id="Kaikki" value="Kaikki">Kaikki</option>` remove `name="Kaikki"` and do the same for all other `<option>`'s with name attributes.

Comment: Nothing changed after removed all the name="" codes, still getting same error.

Comment: why you have select twice ? Same name : `<select name="Vaikutusten vahvuus"` . And what is this `Käyttökelpoisuus: luokka='$Käyttökelpoisuus'";` ??? Colon `:` in a database field name ??? Rethink design your database. DB  fields without spaces and no special characters. That makes coder life a lot easier.

Comment: Good catch @moskito-x I missed that select name="", copy paste error while trying to save time. The database column names are not my choices, doing this website for someone else, if the names break stuff I need to change it later on. Just testing the database connection  for now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we shorten your `if (isset($_POST ...` something you can clearly see. This instruction

```
$results = $conn->query($query);
```

is always executed, regardless of whether isset returns true or not.

```
if (isset($_POST['Kohderyhmä']) &&
 ...)
{
  $Kohderyhmä = get_post($conn, 'Kohderyhmä');
  ...
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta`...."
}

$results = $conn->query($query);
```

So if only one field has not been filled out correctly, the error is always the same :
`PHP Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in ...`.
 This makes it difficult to determine where the fault really comes from.

**Place the curly bracket } behind database logic.**

```
if (isset($_POST['Kohderyhmä']) &&
 ...)
{
  $Kohderyhmä = get_post($conn, 'Kohderyhmä');
  ...
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta`...."
  $results = $conn->query($query);
  if (!$results) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);
  $rows = $results->num_rows;
  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
   {
     $results->data_seek($j);
     $row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     ....
   } 
}
?>
```

create a short test program to test only the database. Set only really necessary data fields in the query

**test.php**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

$Kohderyhmä = "KohderyTest"; // replace with really existing values

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta` WHERE Kohderyhmä='".$Kohderyhmä."' ";
$results = $conn->query($query);
if (!$results) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

  while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<h3>" . $row['Nimi'] . "</h3><br />";
    echo $row['Kohderyhmä'] ."<br /><br />";
  }
$results->free();
?>
```

Add hardcoded variables `$Näytön_aste = "reallyExistingValue";` , add query data field for data field and watch when it starts to stutter.

---

Also we can not see your function `get_post()`

If you mean the Wordpress function `get_post()`, your call to the function is wrong.

> I can well imagine that the failure from the function `get_post()` comes.
>   And you always false or empty values assigns.

```
$Kohderyhmä = get_post($conn, 'Kohderyhmä');
```

assign it direct.

```
$post = $_POST;
if (isset($post['Kohderyhmä']) &&
...)
{
$Kohderyhmä = $post['Kohderyhmä'];
...
```

---

Also you are using all select fields from the `<form>`, in the query.

4 Select's with 8,6,6,6 options means

8x6x6x6 == 1728

**1728 possibilities** are you shure you have one datarecord where all values matches.

```
WHERE Ko...='$Ko...' AND `Näy...`='$Näy...' AND `Vai...`='$Vai...' AND `Käy...`='$Käy...'";
```

`WHERE` All four Datafields must match to get a result !!!!!!!!!!!!!

You have to find a combination where all four values simultaneously exist.

---

UPDATE

> OP new question :
>   If you want empty or some named values stop searching for a value in
>   database.
>
> required every single variable to be found in the database which it
>   didn't find because I couldn't set the variable and there is no value
>   for "Kaikki" in the database, the word "Kaikki" means all choices
>   below that choice in the HTML form and for that I need some PHP

Here comes the new test.php

- 1) don't do `$post['Näytön aste'];` In the form the name is
  `<select name="Näytön aste" style="...">`.
  This will translated by `submit` to
  `$post['Näytön_aste'];` look at  the underscore `_`
  This must be done with all `select name` with spaces in the name !!
- 2) That was the reason why you get not all $_POST[`....`] values !
  OK ?
- 3) replace in your form
  `<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">`
  with
  `<form action="testNew.php" method="POST">`

---

testNew.php

---

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
$post = $_POST;
if (isset($post['Kohderyhmä']) &&
    isset($post['Näytön_aste']) &&
    isset($post['Vaikutusten_vahvuus']) &&
    isset($post['Käyttökelpoisuus']))
 {
  $Kohderyhmä = $post['Kohderyhmä'];
  $Näytön_aste = $post['Näytön_aste'];
  $Vaikutusten_vahvuus = $post['Vaikutusten_vahvuus'];
  $Käyttökelpoisuus = $post['Käyttökelpoisuus'];
 } else { die ("No valid values"); }
    $count = 0;
    $and   = "";
    $query = "";

    if (!empty($Kohderyhmä) && $Kohderyhmä !="Kaikki" ) {
      if ($count > 0) { $and   = " AND ";  }
      $count++;
      $query = $query.$and."`Kohderyhmä`= '".$Kohderyhmä."'";
    }
    if (!empty($Näytön_aste) && $Näytön_aste !="Kaikki" ) {
      if ($count > 0) { $and   = " AND ";  }
      $count++;
      $query = $query.$and."`Näytön aste`= '".$Näytön_aste."'";
    }
    if (!empty($Vaikutusten_vahvuus) && $Vaikutusten_vahvuus !="Kaikki" ) {
      if ($count > 0) { $and   = " AND ";  }
      $count++;
      $query = $query.$and."`Vaikutusten vahvuus`= '".$Vaikutusten_vahvuus."'";
    }
    if (!empty($Käyttökelpoisuus) && $Käyttökelpoisuus !="Kaikki" ) {
      if ($count > 0) { $and   = " AND ";  }
      $count++;
      $query = $query.$and."`Käyttökelpoisuus: luokka`= '".$Käyttökelpoisuus."'";
    }
    if ($count > 0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta` WHERE ".$query;
        } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta`";    
        } 
    echo $query;

if ($results = $conn->query($query)) {
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<h3>" . $row['Nimi'] . "</h3><br />";
    echo $row['Kohderyhmä'] ."<br /><br />";
  }
} else {
  echo "with your choices no records were found";
}
$results->free();
?>
```

Comment: the test.php from your post works. So it wasn't the database connection after all. It's the HTML form -> PHP script part what I can't figure out. How do I create and use variables where HTML form sends data to the PHP script which then uses the received data? The database connection failed in the first place because it required every single variable to be found in the database which it didn't find because I couldn't set the variable and there is no value for "Kaikki" in the database, the word "Kaikki" means all choices below that choice in the HTML form and for that I need some PHP

Comment: ^ too long reply, continued here --> So how do I set some PHP script to pick the data which is being sent to the script and  efficiently use it to query the database for things what actually are in the database? And no, the get_post has nothing to do with WordPress which I don't even use, found that code snippet inside ISNB 978-1-491-91866-1 and tried to modify the snippet to be used in my own script which failed as you can tell from my script..

Comment: I already voted it as helpful (up arrow) but it didn't solve all of my problems. Although I don't even know all the problems in my code. I don't expect full pre-made script for my problem, I just need advice by examples on what I need to know.

Comment: the testNew.php file just echoes the MySQL query, how do I pass that query to the database to retrieve the values from there?

Comment: Did you not see next line after **echo $query;** it is **$results = $conn->query($query);** ?????

Comment: I don't understand any of the PHP or MySQL code. I do see the echo but I don't understand what that conn->query part even means..

Comment: Did you get an output ? you have to improve the while loop I can not see wether **echo "<h3>" . $row['Nimi'] . "</h3><br />";** is enough.

Comment: This is what the script outputs; SELECT * FROM `tietokanta` WHERE `Kohderyhmä`= 'Alakouluikäiset' AND `Näytön aste`= 'Heikko' AND `Vaikutusten vahvuus`= 'Kohtalainen' AND `Käyttökelpoisuus: luokka`= 'Ei_arvioitu' -- it does not show any of those echo $row lines at all, just the query part is shown

Comment: Do not use all at once !!!!! Try only **ONE** valid Field , let all other stay at  `Kaikki` ! The chance is 1 to 1728 if you use all fields.

Comment: It works one at a time, both echoes the query and shows results. Do I need to create 1728 blank fields in the database for it work or how do I create no results found error message?

Comment: I do not know how many records your database has! It's probably the only one choice brings a success. Search out a record from the database, note the present values and then add them to your form input fields, that should bring you the desired result. **I have my answer after `echo $ query` changed. Please replace the old content with the new content**

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tietokanta`
    WHERE Kohderyhmä='{$Kohderyhmä}' AND `Näytön aste`='{$Näytön_aste}' AND `Vaikutusten vahvuus`='{$Vaikutusten_vahvuus}' AND `Käyttökelpoisuus: luokka`='{$Käyttökelpoisuus}'";
```

Replace your query with this, and try.

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Empty query in /home/user/public_html/folder/script.php on line 25 --- line 25 contains code:   $results = $conn->query($query);